# Shopping cart with only cookies

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, httpcookie

I am trying to create a webshop. First of all I can read Products from my Database and can show them in my Views. Now I want to create a Shopping cart where can I store the Products(ProductName,Price,Quantity,...). I have a View called "Details", where I see all Products with price etc.There is a Button called "Into Shopping Cart". With this button im sending the required informations into my `ShoppingCartController`/`CreateShoppingBasket` (Method name), where I collect the data from my `FormCollection`, to create a cookie but this doesnt work......

Quick Question:

How can I realize a Shopping Cart/Basket ONLY with Cookies (no DatabaseConnection but maybe Models but I have no idea). Is there any Cookie Array or can I store my Cookies (with same name for example Cookie["basket"]) into a Array,List ... ? and then read from this Collection all cookies on a view.

Sorry for my english Guys

Comment: But what if cookies is not enabled in users browser or cookies is not supported by user browser.

Comment: Instead of Cookies, you can make use of session (*but in-proc state for session.*)

Comment: @Rajput, it is only a offline Project. Hmm the user should change his browser ^^.

Comment: @mmushtaq, you have any examples ?

Comment: here is sample code check it shoppingcart.cs class. https://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/ . hope this will serve your purpose

Comment: @Rajput1 Thanks Dude, I will check it out!